# Stress Test Hard Drive attached to a LSI controller on Hyper-V

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, lsi, stress-testing, iops

I have a LSI 9265-8i controller running on Hyper-V.

How can I stress-test the hard disks in-situ?

I'd like to test things like iOPS, seek times etc.